# How to protect secret keys in Vue3?

Tags: node.js, security, vuejs3

I recently read the vueJS website that says:

> WARNING Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your
> app! Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone
> can view them by inspecting your app's files.

### Current Situation

I have an API that I created with node js. Which serves data from my postgres database.

The api is hosted on an ubuntu server which is protected by NGINX basic auth. I use a username and password (via .htpasswd) to access the api.

My Vue App sends a fetch request to my API like this:

```
async getStuff() {
            await axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url: MyAPIUrl,
                auth: {
                    username: this.authAdmin, 
                    password: this.authPassword,
                },

            })
                .then((data) => {
                    //do stuff
                })
...
```

As you can see, inside that fetch request I have Basic Auth username and password. So this means the username and password is inside VUE, and therefore it is visible to the browser.

I did a lot of research and I cannot understand how to provide my Vue App with access to my api (which requires authentication) without exposing private keys.

**Is there another way?**

I read online that I need to "handle this on the back end". But I do not understand how I can do that and still give my Vue app access to the data from the DB?

Comment: Everything in the front end can be revealed when the user visits a page. So don't store any private information in the front end. If you don't require the user to log in to use your function, just make your API public and remove the authentication

Comment: The API holds private data. I cannot make it public @Duannx

Comment: What type of private data? Data related to an individual user or what?

Comment: No, so I have the basic auth username and password inside the fetch request. I use this to access my api endpoint. The username and password needs to be private. Not sure how though

Comment: You are making the wrong design. When the API is called from the front end, it should not contain any authentication because the authentication here is useless. It does not relate to Vue at all. It applies to all web applications.

Comment: I see. So how do I get data from my psql database into my vue front end? What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Usually, you write a backend that connects to your DB and exposes an API that the client can use. Don't connect to your DB straight from your frontend

Comment: That is exactly how it is setup. my backend is connected to my DB, which exposes my API which is protected by basic auth. That is what my post says.

My question is how to I access the exposed API from vue if I need to pass basic auth credentials??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, I solved this by decoupling the authentication process.

For the backend: I used jwt.io to protect my api routes. The problem I was having is that I was protecting my api routes with `.htpasswd`. This is why I was passing the auth: {} in my requests from the front end.

By changing to jwt, I am now able to communicate by secure token.

Note - I also use bycrypt to hash my passwords too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store sensitive information like API keys inside your application.

The API keys and other sensitive info can be passed in from the environment in which the deployment is done.
You can configure it while creating the pipelines.

**Another way of handling it in the backend**

One possible solution is to remove the authentication and add the front-end URL to the list of accessible endpoints under CORS.

Comment: Did you see the quote from the Vue CLI site? Warning not to put private keys in env variables? 

How will the cors solution work?

Comment: Usually, the keys are stored in YML files(property files) in production, which you can configure while creating scripts to build the pipeline. Coming to the CORS, just disable all other domains from accessing your API.